# Send wrapper from LWC to APEX

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, json, wrapper-class, lwc-wire-adapter

Hi everybody I am trying to send a wrapper from LWC to an apex class. For that I have the function handleValidation which is triggered when the user clicks the button validate:

```
 wrapperToApexClass;
handleValidacion(event){
    console.log('inside button handler');
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(element =>{
        element.reportValidity();
    })
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-combobox').forEach(element =>{
        element.reportValidity();
    })
    this.wrapperToApexClass = this.createWrapper();
    console.log('whats inside the wrapper...'+ this.createWrapper() );

}
```

then the wire:

```
@wire(wrapperC101, {wrapperWithInfo: this.wrapperToApexClass})
wiredInfo(result){
    console.log('inside del wire...' + result)
}
```

And then the createWrapperFunction that creates the wrapper with the input data the user made:

```
  createWrapperJSON;
createWrapper(){
    console.log('entrando a create wrapper ');
    this.createWrapperJSON = {
            header: {
                name: this.name
            },
    .....
    return JSON.stringify(this.createWrapperJSON);
   }
```

So when the user clicks the button it triggers the handleValidation that calls the createWrapper() to create the wrapper with the user inputs. Once the wrapper is created I send the wrapper created to the wire function.
But the problem is that I am getting the next error: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wrapperToApexClass')'
I think the mistake may be in the @wire line but I do not know.
Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

It's true; your wire property needs to be reactive in order to work:

```
@wire(wrapperC101, {wrapperWithInfo: '$wrapperToApexClass'})
```

But, note that you won't be able to perform any database actions with this parameter, because wire methods must be cached and are therefore not idempotent (e.g. they may not be called every time for the same parameters).

It's likely that you want to call this method imperatively:

```
wrapperC101({ wrapperWithInfo: this.createWrapper() })
```

As a side note, you're not actually verifying that the data is valid before continuing, so you might want to do this first:

```
const inputs = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input, lightning-combobox')];
inputs.forEach((input)=>input.reportValidity());
if(!inputs.every((input)=>input.checkValidity())) {
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@wire(wrapperC101, {wrapperWithInfo: '$wrapperToApexClass'})
wiredInfo(result){
    console.log('inside del wire...' + result)
}
```

change this.wrapperToApexClass to '$wrapperToApexClass'. This is the way to pass variable to wire method.